# CLASSPATH variables not showing up for root user in CentOS 6.6

Tags: centos, centos6

I am running CentOS 6.6 on VmWare Player. I have added path

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:<path/to/jars>
```

of the required jar files to ***.bash_profile*** which resides in my home folder.

Also on executing the following command:

```
gvanjoic@localhost$ echo $CLASSPATH
```

It displays the classpath as expected. But, there are some tasks that I need to run as root user. So on running the following commands, the output is not as expected.

```
gvanjoic@localhost: su
Password:
root@localhost gvanjoic$ echo $CLASSPATH
```

**Output**

```
.
```

Consequently, I can't execute the tasks. What am I possibly doing wrong here. Help appreciated.

FYI, *gvanjoic* is not in *sudoers* list.

Comment: I believe, this question to be on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.bashrc` in *your* homefolder is only executed for *your* user.

Thus when logging in as root, it's not being executed, and root gets a "clean" shell. You probably want to put these lines into `/etc/profile` if they're valid for the whole system, and not just for your user.

Comment: Thanks. Can you just give me an idea where to exactly put those lines in /etc/profile . I tried to put EXPORT CLASSPATH = $CLASSPATH: <path/to/jars> in /etc/profile too but then it gave me errors saying "Illegal character =".

Comment: That is not a question of where, but a question of syntax. Remove the space before `=`.

Comment: Ohh. Will give it a try and keep you posted.

Comment: In addition to what @Marcus Müller says, try doing `su -` instead of just `su`

Comment: Also `export` needs to be lowercase and on a separate line (because `/etc/profile` is executed by Dash etc so you cannot use Bash syntax extensions).  I.e. no spaces on either side of the equals sign and export separately. `CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:<path/to/jars>; export CLASSPATH`

Answer (score 0):

Also try "su -" as the "-" indicates that when you change users, .bashrc should be exported

from "man su"

```
   -, -l, --login
       Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.

       When - is used, it must be specified as the last su option. The other forms (-l and --login) do not have this
       restriction.
```